# How to know if the image data-set is linearly separable or not?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, svm

In the following code, when I pass `kernel='linear'`, the cross-validation accuracy is around 90% but when I pass `kernel='rbf'`,  the cross-validation accuracy is around 40%. Doesn't `rbf` kernel work for linear classification too ?
The classification problem is to classify letters(A-Z) i.e.no. of classes=26. Each image(total:340) data is gray-scale and has size of: 20*10.
As, numerical features can easily be visualized by using simple scatter plot. Is there any better idea than visualizing images using dimensionality reduction techniques (e.g.PCA) ?
How to know if the image data-set is linearly separable or not ?

```
from sklearn.svm import SVC

np.random.seed(42)
shuffle_index = np.random.permutation(340)
shuffled_X, shuffled_y = X_train[shuffle_index], y_train[shuffle_index]

model = SVC(kernel='linear', probability=True)
model.fit(shuffled_X, shuffled_y)

print(cross_val_score(model, shuffled_X, shuffled_y, cv=2))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer : You can be pretty sure that an image dataset is linearly separable (as long as it is small enough and "natural"), but the separation is useless since it will not extend to the validation and testing set.

The difference of performance between linear and rbf kernels may be due to strong overfitting in the case of the rbf kernel. One solution is, if possible, to get more data. Obviously, this is not always possible, so if not, I'd stick to the linear classifier. After all, the cross-validation should be use to select which model works best.

To be honest, I'm amazed that you can obtain 90% accuracy with such small data with 26 classes !

Comment: I would argue that most image datasets are linearly separable but the separation is useless. Because images usually live in a high-dimensional space, and as long as you have more features than samples everything is linearly separable (with probability 1). Linear separability only talks about the training set, not generalization, so the question is not really relevant in high dimensions. The answer for what generalizes best is cross-validation.

Comment: You're entirely right, I'm changing my answer right now